# How can I implement my own basic unix shell in C?

Tags: c, unix, shell, command-line, interpreter

I'm a newbie to process and thread management. My Shell should understand `PATH` environment variable. It can be set and modified. It runs in two ways -interactive & batch mode. Shell is capable of taking more than one job like ls;ps;wc file;cal. I want to get my hands dirty on signals too. So I should handle ^K , ^c as well.

I know I will have to use execs, forks and pipes but just can't get started.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so you should tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 14):

All the unix shells are open-source - so a good place to start may be to read the code.

If you're looking for a good starter article on the subject try [Writing Your Own Shell](http://linuxgazette.net/111/ramankutty.html) from the Linux Gazette.

Another good starting point is to take a look at the source code of [mini-shell](http://code.google.com/p/mini-shell/) just because its one of the smallest to get your head round.

Answer (score 8):

Your main loop is:

- read a line (use `fgets(3)` for a simple shell, `readline(3)` for a fancy one)
- parse the command
- fork and execute the pipelines

To parse the command, there are two common choices. Write a recursive descent parser or use `yacc(1)` to generate one. It's a lot easier to bang out an initial parser using `yacc`, but you can totally get stuck debugging it and it really wants to be context-free. I prefer recursive descent but just about everyone else in the world prefers using yacc. (Technically, `bison`.) If the shell is really really simple, like a homework shell, yacc may be overkill.

To do the lexical analysis you can also roll your own or use flex.

You won't need to use any threads.

Comment: I would recommend `readline()` be used in any case - it will make your life infinitely easier as long as you have to use said shell. But +1 for getting bogged down in yacc/bison. Good tools, but it's a hard task to simplify.

Comment: If you just want to execute programs from yoyur shell, then you don't need a parser & lexer ... however if you do want to do "other" things then I suggest you to use flex+yacc ... *do not roll your own*

Comment: Am getting it. But I want to get my hands dirty on signals too. So I should handle ^K , ^c as well.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the Unix books that describe the main system calls also implement a shell to illustrate how and why you might use the various calls.  Stevens and Rochkind are two such books:

- W Richard Stevens, Stephen A Rago
  [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739)
- Marc J Rochkind
  [Advanced Unix Programming, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543)